# Play json transformers. JsObject to JsObject

Tags: playframework, play-json

I'm expecting JsObject in request body and i want to extract and validate required fields

Request Body:

```
{
    "protoName": "category",
    "clientId": 2
}
```

My Reads:

```
  val userReads: Reads[JsObject] = (
    (__ \ "protoName").read[String] ~
    (__ \ "clientId").read[Int] ~
    (__ \ "additionalFields").readNullable[JsObject]
  )((protoName: String, clientId: Int, addfields: Option[JsObject]) => Json.obj(
    "protoName" -> protoName,
    "clientId" -> clientId,
    "additionalFields" -> addfields
  ))
```

My controller:

```
  def create = Action.async(parse.json) { r =>

    r.body.transform(ModelGroup.userReads).fold(
      err => Future.successful(BadRequest(JsError.toJson(err))),
      g => ModelGroupsDAO.insert(g).map {
        case true => Ok
        case false => BadGateway
      }
    )

  }
```

This code works but it's too much boilerplate code... I mean my Reads.
I thought this code would work:

```
  val userReads: Reads[JsObject] = (
    (__ \ "protoName").read[String] ~
    (__ \ "clientId").read[Int] ~
    (__ \ "additionalFields").readNullable[JsObject]
  )(JsObject.apply _)
```

But it doesn't compile. I think there is a pretty solution like that

Comment: Why not Forms? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms

Comment: In this case i have to write next code:

1. Write Form case class
2. Bind this form
3. Write deserialiaser for that form to JsValue

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonTransformers